# Is there a free API for spell and grammar check?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework

I'm a QA automation engineer looking for a free API or a website for grammar and spell check to automate checks for those errors in web app using Selenium and Java.

Comment: What language? Some of these solve your problem? https://rapidapi.com/collection/grammar-spellcheck-api

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did these attempts fail you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some of these might help you,

https://rapidapi.com/collection/grammar-spellcheck-api

https://rapidapi.com/page-scholar-inc-page-scholar-inc-default/api/jspell-checker/pricing

https://www.grammarbot.io/

https://www.perfecttense.com/pricing

https://www.grammar.com/grammar_api.php

https://serpapi.com/spell-check

https://www.grammar.com/grammar_api.php

https://www.programmableweb.com/news/8-top-apis-spelling/brief/2020/11/08